# How to get color information with mvinch

Tags: c

I know that the functions below exist:

```
chtype inch(void);

chtype winch(WINDOW *win);

chtype mvinch(int y, int x);

chtype mvwinch(WINDOW *win, int y, int x)
```

They are used to get information about the character at the given position.

I can get information about the character, but not get about its color; how I can get color information with functions like these?

I know that there is a mask `A_COLOR` but I don't know how to use it.

My code is as follows:

```
#include <ncurses.h>            /* ncurses.h includes stdio.h */
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char mesg[]="Just a string";        /* message to be appeared on the screen */
    int row,col;                /* to store the number of rows and *
                 * the number of colums of the screen */
    initscr();              /* start the curses mode */

    start_color();          /* Start color          */
    init_pair(1, COLOR_BLUE, COLOR_BLACK);
    attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    refresh();
    mvprintw(1,1,"Hola");

    int x = mvinch(1, 1)&A_CHARTEXT;
    long int y = mvinch(1, 1)&A_COLOR;
    long int z = mvinch(1, 1)&A_ATTRIBUTES;

    mvprintw(10,10,"%c %ld %ld",x,y,z);

    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just compare the result to the `COLOR_PAIR` you want to test for (since that's the attribute in question), for example:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main(void)
{
    initscr();
    start_color();

    init_pair(1, COLOR_BLUE, COLOR_BLACK);
    init_pair(2, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_BLACK);
    init_pair(3, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_BLACK);

    attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
    mvprintw(1, 1, "Sky");

    attron(COLOR_PAIR(2));
    mvprintw(2, 1, "Grass");

    const int color_one = mvinch(1, 1) & A_COLOR;
    const int color_two = mvinch(2, 1) & A_COLOR;

    attron(COLOR_PAIR(3));

    if ( color_one == COLOR_PAIR(1) ) {
        mvprintw(4, 1, "Sky is blue");
    }
    else if ( color_one == COLOR_PAIR(2) ) {
        mvprintw(4, 1, "Sky is green");
    }
    else if ( color_one == COLOR_PAIR(3) ) {
        mvprintw(4, 1, "Sky is white");
    }

    if ( color_two == COLOR_PAIR(1) ) {
        mvprintw(5, 1, "Grass is blue");
    }
    else if ( color_two == COLOR_PAIR(2) ) {
        mvprintw(5, 1, "Grass is green");
    }
    else if ( color_two == COLOR_PAIR(3) ) {
        mvprintw(5, 1, "Grass is white");
    }

    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

which will output, minus the color:

```
Sky
Grass

Sky is blue
Grass is green
```